# $S^{2}$-bundles over complex projective varieties

Tags: complex-geometry, differential-topology

Is there an example of a smooth complex projective variety and an $S^{2}$-bundle over it which is not diffeomorphic to a complex projective variety?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $E\to T^2$ be the $S^2$-bundle over the torus $T^2$ obtained by gluing the trivial bundle over $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ by the identity map in the first coordinate and a reflection in the second coordinate. The torus admits the structure of a smooth complex projective variety, but $E$ isn't orientable, so cannot be diffeomorphic to a smooth complex variety.

Comment: The obvious question is: is that the only obstruction?

Comment: One way of formulating Igor's point is requiring the structure group to be $Diffeo^+(S^2)$.

Comment: Smale proved that the inclusion $SO(3) \hookrightarrow \text{Diff}^+(S^2)$ is an equivalence. As a corollary, the question becomes "Is every $\Bbb{CP}^1$-bundle arising as the unit sphere bundle of a rank 3 oriented vector bundle a complex projective variety?" I don't know the answer. If the rank 3 vector bundle could be lifted to a $U(2)$-bundle, and then given a holomorphic structure, it seems like we could projectivize that to get a complex variety.